# Maxmin Strategy cannot be Weakly Dominated

Tags: game-theory, dominant-strategy

This is homework.

Question: Suppose, $\sigma_i^*$ is a max-min strategy of player $i$. Prove that if $s_i \in \operatorname{supp}(\sigma_i^*)$, then $s_i$ cannot be weakly dominated by any pure/mixed strategy in $S_i$.

My attempt: I am trying to prove by contraction.

Let $v$ be the max-min value for player $i$.

By definition:
$$v = \min_{\sigma_{-i}} u_i(\sigma_i^*, \sigma_{-i})$$

From indifference lemma, I can show that:

$$v = \min_{\sigma_{-i}} u_i(s_i, \sigma_{-i}) = \min_{\sigma_{-i}}u_i(\sigma_i^*, \sigma_{-i})$$

Thus, $$\min_{\sigma_{-i}} u_i(s_i, \sigma_{-i}) \geq \min_{\sigma_{-i}} u_i(s_i', \sigma_{-i})\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \forall s_i' \in \Delta S_i$$

Suppose $\exists \,\, \bar{\sigma_i}$ which weakly dominates $s_i$. Thus,

$$u_i(\bar{\sigma_i}, \sigma_{-i}) \geq u_i(s_i, \sigma_{-i})\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \forall \sigma_{-i}$$

I am able to show that $$\min_{\sigma_{-i}}u_i(\bar{\sigma_i}, \sigma_{-i}) =\min_{\sigma_{-i}} u_i(s_i, \sigma_{-i})=v$$

I am stuck here. Intuitively, I need to show that if $s_i$ is weakly dominated, it cannot be the max-min strategy as there would exist another that will give greater utility than $\min_{\sigma_{-i}} u_i(s_i, \sigma_{-i})$ - which will be a contradiction.

Please feel free to use a completely different approach if you think that the above is not efficient.

Comment: Hi! Do you know the exact definition of weak dominance? Seems like you should use that. Also, a lot of the stuff, e.g., about $s_i'$, seems not to lead to anything, so you can omit that.

Comment: @Giskard: so I realised that the statement is actually wrong (it is easy to construct a counter example). When I went back to the question it had the word 'each'. That is, $s_i$ is in *each* of its max-min strategies. Then it was easy to prove. So the question that I am asking is effectively wrong.